# Converting randomly generated number to String

Tags: java

I had generated one random number using `UUID.randomUUID()`.

I get that random number as

> 615166860114132342

Now I am trying to convert this number to String using, `615166860114132342.toString()`. But I am getting error. Ultimately what I need is to get string format of that random number because I need to check some logs regarding that string. So , how to get it. Is there any way?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: "But I am getting error" What error is it?

Comment: _I am getting error_ is not a very useful description. Always include the entire error in your question. Also, before posting, google the error and see if you can find the solution yourself first.

Comment: UUID.randomUUID() returns UUID. To get String format you can use UUID.randomUUID().toString()

Comment: @Keppil Obviously, If I had found solution in google, I would never had post  this question here.

Comment: tried with `UUID.randomUUID().toString();`??

Comment: It works perfect without any error..Please share the error log

Comment: `UUID.randomUUID().toString();` works fine. show your code. Moreover, `615166860114132342.toString();` is wrong. You can use `UUID u = UUID.randomUUID(); String s = u.toString();`

Answer (score 2):

This work perfectly fine for me.

```
import java.util.UUID;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        System.out.println(uuid);
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
766dedf1-a8cd-4572-a01f-c99b5cd45c50
```

On Pushpa request

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        long value = UUID.randomUUID().getMostSignificantBits();
        System.out.println(value);

        String val = String.valueOf(value);
        System.out.println(val);

        System.out.println(uuid);
    }
}
```

**output**

```
4421583623795395631
4421583623795395631
868b5b0f-92d8-44ca-89c1-d93e98187262
```

Comment: I already have that unique number with me.I just need to convert that number to String.Hope you get me.

Comment: @Pushpa better post the complete code, what is the datatype of the number you are getting, and how..??

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the String representation of a number, use the function `String#valueOf(Object v)`.

Therefore: `String.valueOf(UUID.randomUUID());`

Comment: UUID is not just "a number". `String.valueOf(Object o)` just calls `o.toString()`, which is what he does.